# Error in generating a new Zend Project in Windows

Tags: zend-framework

Whenever i execute

```
C:\xampp\htdocs> zf create project project1
```

the following error appears

```
"php.exe is not recognized as internal or external commands"
```

but when I execute:

```
c:\>zf create project project1
```

it successfully creates a new project in C drive.

but I want to create a project in C:\xampp\htdocs

How can i create a new zend project in C:\xampp\htdocs folder instead of C: drive

Answer (score 4):

You probably have to add the PHP directory path to the PATH variable in environment variables in your Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Right click My Computer, select Properties, then click Advanced tab. From that panel, click the Environment Variables button. Then you can see the System Variables list. select Path and click edit button. At the end of the Variable value, add a semicolon (;) then provide your zend framework library path there.